# Changing the name pattern for a new branch in Eclipse/Mylyn/EGit

Tags: eclipse, egit, mylyn

Whenever I create a new git branch, while a Jira Task is active, the branch name is automatically the following pattern: `issue_<issue-key>-<shortened issue-summary>`.

Is there a way to change the branch name pattern? Maybe I can use the same variable names as in the Commit Comment Template.

I'm using:
Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.9.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201803200915
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.3 (4.7.3)
Mylyn 3.23

Thanks in advance 
Stefan